# Can't get voiceStateUpdate when user disconnect from server

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a function of automatized channels,

All changes are triggered with voiceStateUpdate event.

All work very good but when a user disconnect from server, voiceStateUpdate is not called...

So how can i know if user leave with disconnection from server ?

UPDATE :

I finally got it in voiceStateUpdate, I just dont check if newMember or oldMember, I make my channels update directly by Client and not by the user.

Comment: Maybe this will help [Github](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2466)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no `voiceStateUpdate` event emitted when a Member disconnects from a voicechannel by leaving the Guild. This is a limitation with Discord itself, not the library.

I'd suggest using the `guildMemberRemove` event, which emits a `GuildMember` object. You can use that Object to loop through all the voicechannels in the Guild and check which one the Member disconnected from when leaving.

Answer (score 0):

You can save users who are in the voice channel and then checking if the user who left the guild is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing, `voiceStatusUpdate` does not fire when a user has exit. [This seems to be an issue with Discord itself.](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2466) The `guildMemberRemove` event does fire, though. So to work around this, you must create an array that holds the user's ID, and if a member leaves, check if they were in a voice channel. If you want to monitor multiple channels, you can put all of the channels in an object with the channel ID as a key, and the array of participants (using their IDs, to preserve memory) as the value.

Depending on what method you choose, the resulting object might look like this.

```js
{
    "channel1ID": ["member1ID", "member2ID"],
    "channel2ID": ["member3ID", "member4ID"]
}
```

Now when a member disconnects, simply remove their name from the array of the voice channel they were in. When a member leaves, check every array for their ID. Using this, you'll also be able to get the ID of the channel the member was originally part of.